# NodeJS/PostgreSQL Errors

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am setting up a Node app that has connections to multiple databases. I am using a map to create Pools for all my databases as such:

```
const stnPool = new Map();
async function getOtherDb(stnName){
   if(!stnPool.has(stnName)){
    stnPool.set(stnName,  new Pool({
      host: 'localhost',
      database: stnName.toLowerCase(),
      user: USERNAME,
      password: PASSWORD,
      port: 5432,
      max: 2000,
      idleTimeoutMillis: 0,
      connectionTimeoutMillis: 0,
    }))
   }
   return stnPool.get(stnName);
}
```

PostgreSQL currently has 10 'station' databases. I have 10 remote servers that connect to my server and upload data every 3 seconds. I also have an X number of clients that connect to view the uploaded data in realtime. Bot Server and Client connections connect to upload/request data via Websockets.

To establish aan query a Pool connection:

```
var uvDb = await db.getOtherDb("wx_uv")

if( uvDb != -1 ) {
    const dbT = await uvDb.connect()
    ... do various db queries ...
    dbT.release()
}
```

After a few hours of getting Server uploads and Client requests I get this error:

```
/.../node/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287
const message = name === 'notice' ? new messages_1.NoticeMessage(length, messageValue) : new messages_1.DatabaseError(messageValue, length, name);
^
error: parallel worker failed to initialize
at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/.../node/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
at Parser.handlePacket (/.../node/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
at Parser.parse (/.../node/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/.../node/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
at Socket.emit (node:events:365:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:314:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
length: 163,
severity: 'ERROR',
code: '55000',
detail: undefined,
hint: 'More details may be available in the server log.',
position: undefined,
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
schema: undefined,
table: undefined,
column: undefined,
dataType: undefined,
constraint: undefined,
file: 'parallel.c',
line: '826',
routine: 'WaitForParallelWorkersToFinish'
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on what causes this?

=======UPDATE=======
Tried adding a try/catch to release the connection as well:

```
if( uvDb != -1 ) {
    const dbT = await uvDb.connect()
    try{
        ... do various db queries ...
        dbT.release()
    } catch (err) {
        dbT.release()
    }
}
```

But now I get other errors...

"error: lost connection to parallel worker"

"error: parallel worker failed to initialize"

Comment: It is possible to leak connections if you only release them at the end of successful execution. You can check the DB for the number of active connections.

Comment: Changed my code to include a 'finally', and moved the .release() to there. That coupled with using pg-pool explicitly, some databae index fine-tuning and now I'm running perfectly.
Thanks for the help @Kemal. Pushed me in the right direction!

Comment: A likely cause of this error message is having a query where you might have a lot of where (or WHERE IN) clauses. Could you please check if that might be the case or a possible scenario?